# Getting this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

It seems to think some number here is a string even though I've converted everything to a float. help?

```
starttime = float(0.0)
endtime = float(8000.0)
print('Total Time:')
z = float(endtime - starttime)
if z<=float(60.0):
    print(z+ ' seconds')
elif z>float(60):
    print(z/float(60.0) +' minutes')
elif z>float(3600.0):
    print(z/float(3600) +' hours')
```

Comment: The problem is likely when you try to concatenate a string and a float in the `print()`; you should convert the float to a string when you do that. Additionally, you should post your actual error if you want useful help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your print statements. You need to convert your floats to strings before concatenating floats and strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: starttime = float(0)
    ...: endtime = float(8000)
    ...: print('Total Time:')
    ...: z = endtime - starttime
    ...: if z<=60:
    ...:     print(z+ ' seconds')
    ...: elif z>60:
    ...:     print(str(z/60) +' minutes')
    ...: elif z>3600:
    ...:     print(str(z/3600) +' hours')
    ...:     
Total Time:
133.33333333333334 minutes
```

There was a lot of redundance and boilerplate in your code.

Once you declare a float:

1. Any arithmetic operation on that float always results to a float; so no need to call `float` again on the result
2. To convert a float to a string use the built-in function `str` so that you can concatenate with another string like `minutes` and be able to pass it to the `print` function as it expects.

Comment: @CirdanDorthonion if it solved your problem please consider validating my answer by clicking on the `OK` button and don't forget to `upvote` too